# Trigger Angular NG IF from child component

Tags: angular

I have difficulties of getting an trigger from a "child" component to trigger a ngif in the app.component.ts.

I will try to explain the structure of the project.

In app.component.html my router-outlet is defined like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I also have a menu component, which is included like this.

```
<app-menu *ngIf="toggle"></app-menu>
```

The user provides his/hers credentials in the login.ts component, this component generates a new menu, for that user. Here is where the problem is, I am not able to trigger the ngIf in app.ts from login.ts. When I refresh the page, I get the correct menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a binding from Parent to Child to pass back some parameter to `app.ts` based upon some event that happens in `login.ts`.

[See Component Interaction Angular docs.](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Would it be correct to call the login.ts a child of app.ts (where the router is)?

Comment: Yea, I'm not super sure what your component structure looks like, but I'm assuming there isn't a direct parent -> child relationship between `app.ts` and `login.ts` because of your comment.  You could just create several bindings up and down the component hierarchy, or you could create a "Service" that's injected into `app.ts`.   https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4.  You would end up injecting the service into both the components that will need the variable. Set the varible in one and read in another.

Answer (score 2):

Add a template variable to your `app.component.html`:

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-menu *ngIf="toggle" #menu></app-menu> <!-- Please note the template variable!  -->
```

In your `app.component.ts`, you'll want to gain access to the child by using the [`@ViewChild()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('menu') menu;

  // this is how you'll access toggle to get it to work with your code.
  get toggle() {
    return this.menu.toggle;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had some other issues, so I was not able test this before now. Was I incorrect when I assume that I can access the toggle from any component? When I try to access it from login.ts it just tells me I "core.js:1671 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'toggle' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to implement a `BehaviorSubject` in a service to which the app.component can subscribe to. The subscriber watches for any changes to it and you can  update the component accordingly

A sample can be seen at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-using-behaviou-subject

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where ngIf component was not loading to dom even if its true.
stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-error-when-child-component-has-ngif

solved it by adding viewChild component